Manually color columns in pandas
I have a list of colors that created manually;
colmap = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green']

and also have a pandas dataframe df with same length of my colmap
Percent
0   -0.5
1   0.2
2   0.8
3   -0.3
4   0.6

I want to apply the colors to only Percent column, df.style.applymap doesn't work because it requires a function to apply styles. I couldn't figure out how to apply without a lambda function.
Thanks in advance

Could you add the code for creating your plots?

@James hi, no it's not for plots i want to do this for my report in jupyter notebook

why not use a function? special reason for this?

@BendingRodriguez hi, because colors is not determined by a criteria

Also, what logic should the coloring of the percent values follow?

@BendingRodriguez that is why i shared colmap list. those colors should be applied by the same order

you can still build a function depending on the index of the row to do this.

You could pass a DataFrame to style. The callable doesn't need to use the input data:
df.style.apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
        {'Percent': [f'background-color:{x}' for x in colmap]}, index=x.index
    ),
    axis=None,
)

NB. since the styling DataFrame should be aligned, you still should pass the index.
Output:

Example with another column:

mapping to several columns
If you want to use different mappers for different colors:
other_colors = ['background-color:white', 'background-color:pink',
                'background-color:teal', 'background-color:pink',
                'background-color:white']

df.style.apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
        {'Percent': [f'background-color:{x}' for x in colmap],
         'other': other_colors,
        }, index=x.index
    ).reindex(columns=x.columns),
    axis=None,
)

Or even:
colmap = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green']
other_colors = ['white', 'pink', 'teal', 'pink', 'white']

df.style.apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
        {'Percent': colmap,
         'other': other_colors
        }, index=x.index
    ).radd('background-color:')
     .reindex(columns=x.columns),
    axis=None,
)

Or using a variant of @antoine's approach, with axis=0 and a dictionary:
colors = {'Percent': ['green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green'],
          'other': ['white', 'pink', 'teal', 'pink', 'white']
         }

def lst_to_property(lst):
    if lst is not None:
        return [f'background-color:{x}' for x in lst]

df_.style.apply(lambda c: lst_to_property(colors.get(c.name, None)), axis=0)



how about using row indices as a criteria so that you keep the colors ordered ?
colored_df = df.style.apply(df.style.apply(lambda x: [f"background-color: {colmap[i]}" for i in x.index] if x.name == 'Percent' else None, axis=0)


That would color all columns, not just "Percent"

indeed, i need to add if x.name == 'Percent' else ""

You could simplify to lambda x: [f"background-color: {colmap[i]}" for i in x.index] if x.name == 'Percent' else None (just 1 check). I still prefer the axis=None approach which is more flexible if you want to color several columns independently ;)

Nice ! but I still need to keep the axis=0 or else the entire dataframe is passed and i cannot use x.name.

Of course, I meant I prefer to construct a DataFrame as I showed in my answer, this way you can easily map multiple columns (that would require a different logic with axis=0)

ok now i get it ! thanks for the tip

I found this while looking for a way to color entire rows arbitrarily.  Thanks!
